# Vega-Lite map not showing up with no error

Tags: vega-lite

I modified this example Vega-Lite map plot https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_trellis.html but nothing shows up, and there are no errors.

Here is the code

```
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "id",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "data/us-10m.json",
          "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
        },
        "key": "id"
      },
      "as": "geo"
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "albersUsa"},
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "encoding": {
    "shape": {"field": "geo", "type": "geojson"},
    "color": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgCsABh1L4NMljQBmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUAGUbmOGhAAggDSiiDqaABMSlBsDLKYaAAc+mEQAPpspABOxDRwyv6ybCAAvgpePn7oAQAyoeGoAIzRsfFmWlGpGdm5+YXFZRXWVYEASvVq2i1xCU1iYko06ZlwOXkF6EWl5SDew-4BAFoTaAsgMTNmAJymi8s96-3bQ77+AMIBJ6gAbNNtqFcAOydJbdVa9DYgLaDXaVd4AeS+iT+s0agKudzBaz6mwGOz2r3QbwAKl8MedWqitJiVtjIdD8XD0AARACiX0aKQu-2aXVpEKeMIJIwAYnVFpMmp1ubMxN8zqD+Y9cc9Yft0ABxT4StCNW4Uy4A0yAmkPHFQvEvEYACQAkhzqQb-mJyYqzfTLWrCSBbdqwpLGuSZZEQfdwcqLarhf5bcyOb8nbMIjoE27w+aGVaY+L-bqTYndQqw3TBYz1T6AHIc5EFpq8tMllVCpkgIKeL7JlGnfMNgVNsveoIATQ7vODUtdxb7keb5ZqfoaEWllN1WlTU4jma9IwAsgvJRFHeO0ab0x6oy2d3GdagImdxxFJ1jp1vo+gd+ybxF9ePATXe5unpviAO72l+CbjloRbPoBF7ljuVZfvmD5LqejYzgOu6Il+QYrgC0FKhmQGXu2X41uOYg6PWG5EXB3o7qSN7mF2t6mNRMG0bO3oVm8oSQYC64ceeXEjBW161t8PY0cJmH+BWn65qgbEsWIjoAZxsnoBW1p8XhjRqdJpZZlpABSumGnqoZCUZ25yTu5n-MmVmETJxkgBWABqXymMuhqJIJLk2cBFYjipWjsYF-ZufCOlMbhFn-oZUW2eg8IhDelEsd+BnWclwHwuMGVjnhPnOe6QUtgACvupy+f8WiJblGFuZVhW1o0HVoS+xHlqMYG1vq6muSluy8SpqF8uVeUtp44nHoCEVTc1I3EohiliMhenfI1kXLcBxIABpfGI5F4YCwJdbBIn+AAqox63xTyiSLWeFXlh5NWoOFLGNBEO1La+LYefdDS6CxAUAz13oAOqfVoP56Ykg1JXtLbQ-1oNHltyNNYD5bQ15P2NARkN0SM0OhYpa4sYCJOvU2AC6ZQgJgWRILIEAAGZsFkCDuKAghsGwADWDA4P44RKJzWRsHzdggFYNhoKADBZII-iK0gBAMBA-CcggUgyPIUs88gsygJgACeOAjJgbA4Gw0hyKEnNwNYqsjBAlSuCUzPC3AlsS5MzNIK46BkHAAwM0oOAy5IcBQJg7DyPLVs2-4jhMKsEA3RAKDM8gWTC-4EdsBAMBIOnShwLIMRqDQshkMrIDl5XVSgJzeSCJKICl6EacjKXTvyMzMSC1kzed3A3f+MGSgD-4ACODDs0nPg0KQpS+0AA)

I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post a sample of your data in 'us-10m.json' file. Do you have a property called `geometry` in the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains rows that are missing the `"id"` entry, which leads to null `geo` entries in the joined data. If you filter out these invalid values, it works as expected for the defined rows ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgCsABh1L4NMljQBmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUAGUbmOGhAAggDSiiDqaABMSlBsDLKYaAAc+mEQAPpspABOxDRwyv6ybCAAvgpePn7oAQAyoeGoAIzRsfFmWlGpGdm5+YXFZRXWVYEASvVq2i1xCU1iYko06ZlwOXkF6EWl5SDew-4BAFoTaAsgMTNmAJymi8s96-3bQ77+AMIBJ6gAbNNtqFcAOydJbdVa9DYgLaDXaVd4AeS+iT+s0agKudzBaz6mwGOz2r3QbwAKl8MedWqitJiVtjIdD8XD0AARACiX0aKQu-2aXVpEKeMIJIwAYnVFpMmp1ubMxN8zqD+Y9cc9Yft0ABxT4StCNW4Uy4A0yAmkPHFQvEvEYACQAkhzqQb-mJyYqzfTLWrCSBbdqwpLGuSZZEQfdwcqLarhf5bcyOb8nbMIjoE27w+aGVaY+L-bqTYndQqw3TBYz1T6AHIc5EFpq8tMllVCpkgIKeL7JlGnfMNgVNsveoIATQ7vODUtdxb7keb5ZqfoaEWllN1WlTU4jma9IwAsgvJRFHeO0ab0x6oy2d3GdagImdxxFJ1jp1vo+gd+ybxF9ePATXe5unpviAO72l+CbjloRbPoBF7ljuVZfvmD5LqejYzgOu6Il+QYrgC0FKhmQGXu2X41uOYg6PWG5EXB3o7qSN7mF2t6mNRMG0bO3oVm8oSQYC64ceeXEjBW161t8PY0cJmH+BWn65qgbEsWIjoAZxsnoBW1p8XhjRqdJpZZlpABSumGnqoZCUZ25yTu5n-MmVmETJxkgBWABqXymMuhqJIJLk2cBFYjipWjsYF-ZufCOlMbhFn-oZUW2eg8IhDelEsd+BnWclwHwuMGVjnhPnOe6QUtgACvupy+f8WiJblGFuZVhW1o0HVoS+xHlqMYG1vq6muSluy8SpqF8uVeUtp44nHoCEVTc1I3EohiliMhenfI1kXLcBxIABpfGI5F4YCwJdbBIn+AAqox63xTyiSLWeFXlh5NWoOFLGNBEO1La+LYefdDS6CxAUAz13oAOqfVoP56Ykg1JXtLbQ-1oNHltyNNYD5bQ15P2NARkN0SM0OhYpa4sYCJOvU2AC6ZQgJgWRILIEAAGZsFkCDuKAnM0IIvhZP4SweY46gABRWJgDAIKwagAJSqoIbBsAA1gwOBi5MSic1kbB83YICy7YoAMFkgj+GbBAMBA-Ccgr0hyKE3O89YaCgJgACeOAjJgbA4GwLvyPrcDWJbIwQJUrglMzGtwD7uvbCASCuOgZBwAMDNKDghuSHAUCYOw8gm77-v+I4TCrBAN0QCgzPIFkGv+FnbAQDASCV0ocCyDEag0LIZBeyAnfd1UAt5IIkogO3oQVyM7eh6nMRq6LJuC3AM-+MGSiL-4ACODDsyXPg0KQpTx0AA)):

```
"transform": [
    {"filter": "isValid(datum.id)"},
    {
      "lookup": "id",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "data/us-10m.json",
          "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
        },
        "key": "id"
      },
      "as": "geo"
    }
  ],
```

[image]